# Docker communication within VPS (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

Tags: docker, web-applications, vps

I am developping a webapp project and started hosting it online.
I got a domain name and a VPS from OVH. I run 2 docker containers within my VPS (front and back).

When I'm connected to my front through my domain name and trying to make any call to the back end, I end up getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED errors.

Both docker containers are up and on the same network

```
[
    {
        "Name": "custom_net",
        "Id": "c4cb2d130ec50ebc383b383eb46e6ea8eef43e8564d9d7e144ee217064dbb48e",
        "Created": "2023-08-24T10:14:24.929617144Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ef1b1022ba515532688326955bbc04e3db02ae26808ebdd3bef4ac8ef6d76e91": {
                "Name": "blindtest-back",
                "EndpointID": "9b67ed7c930948068f3e560ef43d96328c3fda31dee01c8ad5b1014b72c7d28c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f13e26948ae720e06b1d5666e8289bdf68bbc8c99aee99d74f5a861659f839ff": {
                "Name": "blindtest-front",
                "EndpointID": "c390a890f58905af1360b2c2d3bd0f6e6a85f9d5c59cd42071de46f40564ece9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Here is the docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  blindtest-front:
    build:
      context: blindtest-front
    container_name: blindtest-front
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - custom_net

  blindtest-back:
    build:
      context: blindtest-back
    container_name: blindtest-back
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - custom_net

networks:
  custom_net:
    name: custom_net
    driver: bridge
```

If I get into the front container via docker exec -it, I can ping my back-end container but curl doesn't work.

From what I understood searching online, this is because my browser is trying to access the backend api via http://blindtest-back:8000/api/whatever but he doesn't know, only my front end container knows but the request is made from the client browser.

But I cannot find a way to make this work, should I implement a proxy to do redirection ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem origin.

Nothing was wrong with docker, the network or using container names.

My problem is that my backend contenerized service was listening to 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of 0.0.0.0:8000 making it not accessible from anywhere outside the container itself.